# Accessing each estimator in a BaggingClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Imagine I have this:

```
model = BaggingClassifier((base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(), n_estimators=31)
```

I want to acces each `31` estimators, but I do not know how to do it.
I've tried:

```
for _ in model.estimators_:
    # stuff
```

but it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'BaggingClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'
```

But in [BagginClassifier guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html?highlight=bagging#sklearn-ensemble-baggingclassifier) it appears as

> **estimators_ : *list of estimators***. The collection of fitted base estimators.

Comment: have you called 'fit()'?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan the problem is that I want to fit each estimator with different data, so I haven't fitted yet. I know that, therefore, is not very useful to bag them, but it is the way I'm required to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute `estimators_` needs the model to have been fitted first:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import BaggingClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=4,
                            n_informative=2, n_redundant=0,
                            random_state=0, shuffle=False)
clf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=SVC(),
                         n_estimators=3, random_state=0)

clf.estimators_
# AttributeError: 'BaggingClassifier' object has no attribute 'estimators_'

clf.fit(X, y)
clf.estimators_
# result:
[SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
     decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
     max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=2087557356, shrinking=True,
     tol=0.001, verbose=False),
 SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
     decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
     max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=132990059, shrinking=True,
     tol=0.001, verbose=False),
 SVC(C=1.0, break_ties=False, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
     decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='scale', kernel='rbf',
     max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=1109697837, shrinking=True,
     tol=0.001, verbose=False)]
```

Comment: What if I want to fit each one separately?

Comment: @Omar This is another, completely different question altogether. Here you asked about a specific error during access, and you got an answer on that. You are always welcome to accept the answer and open a different question with the specifics.

Comment: you're right about it's a different question, but I do not see any point at opening a new one. Is there any way I can fit each one separately?

Comment: @Omar not that *I*  happen to know of, but someone else might - that's why it is not a bad idea to open a new question, clarifying specifically the issue